# JavaScript + jQuery: Display calculated variable in table instead of console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## Introduction

I have made a calculation based on two dynamic user input number values (inputEks / GNS_EKS_TIME)  + (inputMail / GNS_MAIL_TIME).

The result of the calculation is stored in the variable TimeSum.

## Goal

I want the calculation stored in TimeSum to be displayed in the column Hours used.

## Code

```js
var tr = document.querySelector('tbody tr');
var row = document.querySelector('thead tr');

var th = document.createElement('th');
th.className = "hours_used";
var text = document.createTextNode("Hours used")
th.appendChild(text);
row.appendChild(th);

var th = document.createElement('th');
th.className = "prognose_eks";
th.id = "digit_fast_header"
var text = document.createTextNode("Prognose exp")
th.appendChild(text);
th.style.display = "none";
row.appendChild(th);

var th = document.createElement('th');
th.className = "prognose_mail";
th.id = "digit_fast_header"
var text = document.createTextNode("Prognose mail")
th.appendChild(text);
th.style.display = "none";
row.appendChild(th);

var td = document.createElement('td');
td.className = "hoursUsed";
td.innerHTML = "<input type='number' disabled='disabled' id='result'>"
tr.appendChild(td);

var td = document.createElement('td');
td.className = "inputEks";
td.id = "inputEks" 
td.innerHTML = "<input type='number' class='input1' name = 'inpt[]' >";
tr.appendChild(td);
// new line
var inputEks = td.querySelector('input');

var td = document.createElement('td');
td.className = "inputMail";
td.id = "inputMail" 
td.innerHTML = "<input type='number' class='input2' name = 'inpt[]' >";
tr.appendChild(td);
// new line
var inputMail = td.querySelector('input');

// new code

inputMail.addEventListener('input', chnage);
inputEks.addEventListener('input', chnage);

function chnage() {
  var GNS_EKS_TIME = 9;
  var GNS_MAIL_TIME = 9;
  TimeSum = (parseInt(inputEks.value, 10) / GNS_EKS_TIME) + (parseInt(inputMail.value, 10) /   GNS_MAIL_TIME);
  console.log("########### TEST ############## " + TimeSum);
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead><tr></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><tr></tbody>
</table>
```

## Attempt

The code outputs the calculation through console.log, but ideally it should be dynamically put into the first column if you try to run the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following at the end of your function,

```
const hours = document.querySelector('#result');

if(isNaN(TimeSum)){
  return;
} else {
  hours.value= TimeSum;
}
```

Here i have user query selector method and retrieved the hours used column's input which has `id="result"` then made the value to append your final output.

```js
var tr = document.querySelector('tbody tr');
var row = document.querySelector('thead tr');

var th = document.createElement('th');
th.className = "hours_used";
var text = document.createTextNode("Hours used")
th.appendChild(text);
row.appendChild(th);

var th = document.createElement('th');
th.className = "prognose_eks";
th.id = "digit_fast_header"
var text = document.createTextNode("Prognose exp")
th.appendChild(text);
th.style.display = "none";
row.appendChild(th);

var th = document.createElement('th');
th.className = "prognose_mail";
th.id = "digit_fast_header"
var text = document.createTextNode("Prognose mail")
th.appendChild(text);
th.style.display = "none";
row.appendChild(th);

var td = document.createElement('td');
td.className = "hoursUsed";
td.innerHTML = "<input type='number' disabled='disabled' id='result'>"
tr.appendChild(td);

var td = document.createElement('td');
td.className = "inputEks";
td.id = "inputEks" 
td.innerHTML = "<input type='number' class='input1' name = 'inpt[]' >";
tr.appendChild(td);
// new line
var inputEks = td.querySelector('input');

var td = document.createElement('td');
td.className = "inputMail";
td.id = "inputMail" 
td.innerHTML = "<input type='number' class='input2' name = 'inpt[]' >";
tr.appendChild(td);
// new line
var inputMail = td.querySelector('input');

// new code

inputMail.addEventListener('input', chnage);
inputEks.addEventListener('input', chnage);

function chnage() {
  var GNS_EKS_TIME = 9;
  var GNS_MAIL_TIME = 9;
  TimeSum = (parseInt(inputEks.value, 10) / GNS_EKS_TIME) + (parseInt(inputMail.value, 10) /   GNS_MAIL_TIME);
  console.log("########### TEST ############## " + TimeSum);
  
  const hours = document.querySelector('#result');

  if(isNaN(TimeSum)){
  return;
  } else {
    hours.value = TimeSum;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead><tr></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><tr></tbody>
</table>
```

**Note:** It is not recommended to use the variable name starts with UpperCase.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the displayed text you should change the value based on your calculation in `console.log` :

`document.getElementById('result').value = TimeSum;`

where in this case you've already declared the  "hoursUsed" with `result` as the id, so you can use [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to access it.

Since it was tagged as `jQuery` too you could also access by `$('#result').val(TimeSum);`

Example:

```js
var tr = document.querySelector('tbody tr');
var row = document.querySelector('thead tr');

var th = document.createElement('th');
th.className = "hours_used";
var text = document.createTextNode("Hours used")
th.appendChild(text);
row.appendChild(th);

var th = document.createElement('th');
th.className = "prognose_eks";
th.id = "digit_fast_header"
var text = document.createTextNode("Prognose exp")
th.appendChild(text);
th.style.display = "none";
row.appendChild(th);

var th = document.createElement('th');
th.className = "prognose_mail";
th.id = "digit_fast_header"
var text = document.createTextNode("Prognose mail")
th.appendChild(text);
th.style.display = "none";
row.appendChild(th);

var td = document.createElement('td');
td.className = "hoursUsed";
td.innerHTML = "<input type='number' disabled='disabled' id='result'>"
tr.appendChild(td);

var td = document.createElement('td');
td.className = "inputEks";
td.id = "inputEks" 
td.innerHTML = "<input type='number' class='input1' name = 'inpt[]' >";
tr.appendChild(td);
// new line
var inputEks = td.querySelector('input');

var td = document.createElement('td');
td.className = "inputMail";
td.id = "inputMail" 
td.innerHTML = "<input type='number' class='input2' name = 'inpt[]' >";
tr.appendChild(td);
// new line
var inputMail = td.querySelector('input');

// new code

inputMail.addEventListener('input', chnage);
inputEks.addEventListener('input', chnage);

function chnage() {
  var GNS_EKS_TIME = 9;
  var GNS_MAIL_TIME = 9;
  TimeSum = (parseInt(inputEks.value, 10) / GNS_EKS_TIME) + (parseInt(inputMail.value, 10) /   GNS_MAIL_TIME);
  console.log("########### TEST ############## " + TimeSum);
   document.getElementById('result').value = TimeSum;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead><tr></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><tr></tbody>
</table>
```